# `gnutls/gnutls.h: No such file or directory` while installing latest `cups`

Tags: makefile, printing, gnu-make, cups, gnutls

I am trying to install the latest version of `cups 2.3.3`, I was following
https://fossies.org/linux/cups/INSTALL.md

After the `make` command, I got the foll error.

```
In file included from cups-private.h:21:0,
                 from auth.c:17:
http-private.h:70:14: fatal error: gnutls/gnutls.h: No such file or directory
 #    include <gnutls/gnutls.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [../Makedefs:271: auth.o] Error 1
```

Note that I followed the step

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf build-essential libavahi-client-dev \
     libgnutls28-dev libkrb5-dev libnss-mdns libpam-dev \
     libsystemd-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev zlib1g-dev
```

before going to `make`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing a `gnutls` related package. Try to search which package you need:

```
$ apt-file search gnutls/gnutls.h
libgnutls28-dev: /usr/include/gnutls/gnutls.h
```

Comment: I had installed `libgnutls28-dev` and now I can find `/usr/include/gnutls/gnutls.h`. However, the error is still there. Why?

Comment: Well I tried on my laptop, same thing happened.
`/usr/include/gnutls/gnutls.h` is still there but got the same error.

Comment: Do you happen to also have a complete compilation line? Please share if you do. Somehow your compiler cannot find it, maybe the compilation switches will give a hint.

Comment: could you plz assist me on what you want?

Comment: Before this error there should have been a line like `gcc ...`. Please share this line as well to see how the compiler was invoked.